# Extracting char from string (regex)

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to extracted the bolded character from the sample strings below. The pattern goes like this:

ChunkOfAlphabets_ChunkOfDigits_**CharIWant**_ChunkOfDigits_CharIDontCare

"ABC12**A**1234D"

"ABCD34**B**5678E"

"EF34**C**9101F"

I have came up with the following code. It seems to be working fine but I am wondering is there a more efficient way of doing it, perhaps using regex?

```
    char extractString(string test)
    {
        bool isDigit = false;
        foreach(var c in test)
        {
            if (isDigit && !char.IsDigit(c))
                return c;

            isDigit = char.IsDigit(c);
        }

        return '0';
    }
```

Comment: output for case `AA291F`?

Comment: @rock321987 that's a invalid case becasue it doesn't match the pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using C# LINQ would be easier and more performant (regex involves a lot of overhead):

```
static char ExtractString(string test)
{
    return test.SkipWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c))
               .SkipWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c))
               .FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Comment: for those who like it short `.SkipWhile(Char.IsLetter).SkipWhile(Char.IsDigit).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

First, a regex shouldn't be faster than a good and little algorithm. However, i give you a regex to try it and check what is faster.

The following regex gives me what you wanted:

```
^\D+\d+([A-Za-z])\d+\D+$
```

I suggest you to use https://regex101.com/, it's perfect for test something like that.

Comment: regex101.com should not be used with .Net regexps. Test using a benchmark option at regexhero.net.

Answer (score 1):

This function in C# should do what you expect using regex, however I doubt it's more efficient than a simple algorithm:

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    private char extractChar(string test)
    {
        char charOut = '\0';
        var matches = Regex.Matches(test, "^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+([a-zA-Z])[0-9]+.+");
        if (matches.Count > 0)
            charOut = matches[0].Groups[1].Value[0];

        return charOut;
    }
```

Comment: You have redundant code here. If you expect one match, why use `Regex.Matches`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

> ChunkofAlphabets = [A-Za-z] <--English letters
>
> ChunkOfDigits = [0-9]
>
> CharIWant = can be any character except the digits [0-9]

Assuming above, the regex should be

```
^[A-Za-z]+\d+(\D+)\d+.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ3dB4/3)**

[***C# Code Ideone Demo***](http://ideone.com/TrE0oe)